# How do i add and print a txt file in my Python code?

Tags: python

i'm following a course of python.
I have no programming experience and I'm stuck with this project.

I need to make a Python code where i ask the user a number. If that number is higher then 50 the code needs to make a txt file with a message. Then i have to write a code that print the message from the txtfile. I tried a lot of things and now i have this:

```
number = int(input("give a number:"))
def number():
    f = open("number.txt", "a")
    f.write("The number is bigger then fifty")
    if f.read. getal > 50:
        file= f.read()
        print(file)
        g.close()
```

I know it is wrong but i don't know what to do anymore.
hopefully someone can help me.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `if f.read. getal > 50:`?

Comment: What is `g` in `file = g.read()`?

Comment: Actually i have no idea. I tried to follow a tutorial and they did this.

Comment: And the g.read was wrong. Thanks

Comment: You must have copied something wrong. It's not even close to making sense.

Comment: You have the file opened in write-only mode, you can't read from it. You need to use `a+` mode to write and read. And if you want to read what you wrote, you have to seek back to the beginning of the file.

Comment: You can't use the same name `number` for both the variable and the function. And you never check whether the user's input is greater than 50. You're comparing `f.read.getal` to `50`, but nothing like that exists.

Answer (score 0):

Please use [with](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/with-statement-in-python/) for this, so that Python closes your file automatically. Otherwise, you might forget to close it and get some issues.

```
number = int(input("Enter a number: "))
message = 'Number is > 50'

if number > 50:
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(message)
```

If you want to read your file, you can use with again, but this time without the 'w'(write) argument. You don't have to enter the 'r'(read) argument because it is the default mode.

Comment: What about the part that prints the message from the file?

Comment: exactly! Using `with` is better but honestly I think that is missing the point of the question as @Kim is using 2 files and wants message from a file, not a variable

Comment: i take it back, i just saw the edit to the question and the context of `g`, still the message is not from a variable it should be from a file

Comment: @eisa.exe Are you sure about this? The first message in OP's code doesn't come from a file; it was already there. After this, the message should be read from the file, but then it would be the same, so I am not going to write redundant code here. It's basically just a matter of seconds to get this to work, in any case.

Answer (score 0):

`f.read. getal` is not actually a valid piece of code. And it is `f.read()`, not `f.read`. It is a function that returns a value. To keep your function and code structure, here is the way to do it:
(I also fixed some simple syntax mistakes in your code)
I'm assuming every `g` is supposed to be `f`, that would make more sense.
It is also better not to have a variable and a function have the same name so I changed `number` to `num`

```
num = int(input("give a number:"))

def number(number):
    f = open("number.txt", "a+") # a+ modified according to a comment by @Barmar (I personally don't remember this 
    f.write("The number is bigger then fifty")
    if number > 50:
        file = f.read()
        print(file)
        f.close()
number(num)
```

Comment: why not use `with open(...) as f:` ? More efficient, less opening and closing